# To find the projection matrix onto a subspace along a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $U = \text{span} \{(1,0,1)^t,(1,2,0)^t\} = \{u_1,u_2\}$ and $V = \text{span} \{(-1,1,-1)^t\}$.

I want to find the projection matrix $P$ onto $U$ along the direction of $V$.

---

I know how to find the projection matrix onto a subspace. Let $A = [u_1 \ u_2]$, then $P = A(A^tA)^{-1}A^t$ is the required projection matrix onto $U$.

---

But how to find the **projection matrix onto a subspace along a subspace**?